# How do I handle errors caused by invalid user input in a VB.NET program?

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I am a beginner in VB.NET and I would like to know how do I handle the errors that may appear from the user of my program. For example, I have an triangle area program in wich I ask the user of the program to insert the length of the base and height of the triangle in a textbox. But what if he inserts a letter or something else, like a sign....my program will crash...

I know that one method would be to use **On Error GoTo** but I don't know how. If maybe you can direct me to some link or you could explain how do I handle errors, I would be grateful. Maybe you can even show me other ways to avoid errors from the user input.

This is my small program so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
                Handles Button1.Click

    Dim , Height, ARIA As Integer

    Base = TextBox1.Text
    Height = TextBox2.Text
    ARIA =  Base * Height / 2
    TextBox3.Text = ARIA

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your homework should look like this...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Base, Height, ARIA As Integer
    Try
        Base = TextBox1.Text
        Height = TextBox2.Text
        ARIA = Base * Height / 2
        TextBox3.Text = ARIA
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I got it now...Thank you. It's not a homework I am just trying to learn something new by following different tutorials. And I have set as a goal to learn some VB to help in my construction engineer designer job. As you may figured out English is not my first language...I am a romanian:)

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is:

```
Try
    'Do something dangerous
Catch ex As System.Exception 'catch any error
    'Handle the error here
End Try
```

If you have any "clean-up" tasks that need to be performed *regardless of if any errors occurred* (like closing a file, for instance), do:

```
Try
    'The dangerous code here will get executed
Finally
    'Whether the code throws any exception or not, this part will ALWAYS run
End Try
'If there was any error, then it would be thrown AFTER the end of the 'finally'
```

You can also have more complex exception handlers, like:

```
Try
    'Dangerous code
Catch ex As FormatException
    'This code catches only a FormatException
Catch ex As ArithmeticException
    'This code catches only ArithmeticException
'Any other kind of error is NOT caught
Finally
    'Regardless of whether the error was handled, this part will execute
End Try
'Unhandled exceptions will be thrown before the block continues
```

Comment: May you be a little more accurate...just a few words about what this try structure does...how it works...Please.

Comment: Or maybe an example of this kind of code. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: This a reasonable answer, but you forgot to explain how to *filter* inputs from the user in the first place. Throwing/catching exceptions is expensive. If you are reasonably certain that the user might screw something up, you should check to be sure that they didn't, first. Tossing in a `If` statement is much cheaper than a `Try`-`Catch` block. Choosing to only explain try/catch to an admitted beginner is definitely a mistake in my book.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the others already wrote, I figured it might be instructive for you to see what your code would look like using "Visual Basic best practices". You might not be ready for all of this yet, but maybe you find some of the concepts useful:

```
' This is at the top of the file and forces us to do explicit instead
' of implicit conversions. You can also set this in the project settings
Option Strict On    

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Handles Button1.Click

    ' It's convention to have local variables start with a lower-case character
    Dim base, height, aria As Integer 

    Try
        ' Since Option Strict is on, we need to explicitly convert
        ' Strings to Integers.
        base = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text) 
        height = Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)

    ' The documentation of Int32.Parse (Integer is a Visual Basic alias for
    ' Int32) says that a FormatException and an OverflowException can occur,
    ' so we catch and handle them here.
    Catch ex As FormatException
        MsgBox("Base or Height is not a number")
        Return   ' Leave the sub '

    Catch ex As OverflowException
        MsgBox("Base or Height is too large")
        Return
    End Try

    aria = base * height / 2
    TextBox3.Text = aria.ToString()    ' Convert the Integer back into a String

End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can use TryParse to convert an Integer into a String. It will not throw an exception but rather return false if the conversion fails:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Handles Button1.Click

    Dim base, height, aria As Integer 

    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, base) = False OrElse Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, height) = False Then
        MsgBox("Base or Height is invalid")
        Return
    End If

    aria = base * height / 2
    TextBox3.Text = aria.ToString()
End Sub
```

That way, you avoid exception handling altogether (in this case).

Comment: `TryParse` is the correct approach here. The code is even shorter/simpler, a double win. (But thanks for taking the time to fill in this gap in the existing answers.)

Comment: @Cody: I also prefer `TryParse`. In this case, however, I think that `Parse` + exception handling is acceptable as well, since the user entering non-numeric data in the "base" or "height" field is an *exceptional circumstance* (it's not "normal control flow", it's "something went wrong").

Comment: I disagree... A user making a silly mistake is not all that exceptional. You expect that the parse could possibly fail, or you wouldn't be trying to catch and handle the exception in the first place. Personally, I'd make the change at the site of the text entry control, but that's getting a little more advanced. I agree that in this simple case, it doesn't matter either way, though.

Comment: A big THANK YOU! for taking the time to discuss my small problems. You are a big help and I am very greatfull. I will annoy you even further with basic questions:). Again if anyone knows a good tutorial for me to follow I would be ecstatic.  @Cody: You helped me before; thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I still wonder how does the On Error GoTo statement works... Isn't that another way to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: @Alex: `On Error GoTo` is legacy syntax from older, incompatible versions of Visual Basic (specifically, VB 6). You shouldn't use it in VB.NET at all, but especially not for newer projects. It's called *unstructured* error handling, and it's a huge pain in the rear. The newer *structured* error handling (the try/catch business) is *much* easier to use, and has been a godsend to VB developers all over the world. Technically, yes, you *could* use `On Error GoTo` to solve this problem, but you really shouldn't. Honestly, the best thing to do is just put out of your mind that it even exists.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, `On Error Goto` is another way to do error handling in VB.NET. However, it mainly exists for backwards compatibility with older Visual Basic versions.  Microsoft recommends to use `try-catch` ("structured error handling") instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx

Comment: Thank you both! I will forget about that On Error Goto syntax then.

Comment: @Cody or @Heinzi : How do I write the cotangent of an angle? This is what I was able to do so far looking on the internet                  :            alfa = (1 / Math.Tan(M)) * 100
            Label14.Text = alfa.ToString()

Comment: @Alex: Sounds good, the contangent is indeed (1/Math.Tan(angle)). Why do you multiply the cotangent with 100? Note that angles need to be in radiant, not in degrees. See the help page of Math.Tan for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.tan.aspx

Comment: @Heinzi: Thanks for that! I was trying actualy to get the angle of a given slope. It's a usefull program 4 me because I need almost daily to calculate slopes, elevation and to interoplate data on different projects since I am an civil engineer. I got it now why it did not work. I know that the tangent of the base angle divided by 100 will give me the slope. Therfor the reverse is also true the cotangent of a slope in meters times 100 gives me the angle.(this works with a hand calculator-try it).

Comment: But I did not take into acount the fact that I was calculating in degrees and not in radians. Do you know a way to convert into degrees? If you do please let me know.. I would be greatful.

Comment: This is what I came up with this far:alfa = -(1 / Math.Tan(M * (180 / Math.PI))) * 100
            Label14.Text = alfa.ToString() Maybe you can see the error  because I can't find the bug. I hope someone can tell me what is the correct way.                                                    Whith respect for your work, Alexander

Comment: @Alex: I guess you're doing the conversion the wrong way around: `M * (180 / Math.PI)` converts a *radiant* M into *degrees*. If *M* is in degrees and you want radiant, use `M * (Math.PI / 180)`.